# How to Update a numeric field with the SUM of the numeric field in a different table MS-ACCESS 13

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a supply inventory database with 3 tables. Main (Warehouse Stock), Supply Issue Table, and Supply Purchases Table. All three tables share the relationship ITEM #. Supply Issue and Supply Purchases both log  transactions (i.e. Item #, Quantity Issued or purchased). I need to have the Purchase and Issue tables update the total quantity in the Main Table

I created an update query to update the two fields in the main table(PQuantity/IQuantity). Then a third auto-calculated field (MQuantity) which is (PQuantity-IQuantity). I did it this way because I understood I couldn't run an update query for an auto-calculated field?

Here's the update query SQL for purchases:

```
UPDATE [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)] 
INNER JOIN [Supply Purchases Table] 
ON [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)].[ITEM #] = [Supply Purchases Table].[ITEM #] 
SET [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)].PQUANTITY = +[Supply Purchases Table]![QTY  ADDED];
```

Here's the update query SQL for issues:

```
UPDATE [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)] 
INNER JOIN [Supply Issue Table] 
ON [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)].[ITEM #] = [Supply Issue Table].[ITEM #] 
SET [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)].IQUANTITY = +[Supply Issue Table]![QTY ISSUED];
```

The problem with this is it will only total the last purchase or issue that was input. I also get "Type conversion" errors.

Am I making this too difficult?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to add`QTY ADDED`to the old value of`PQUANTITY`like:

```sql
UPDATE
    [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)]
    INNER JOIN
        [Supply Purchases TABLE]
    ON
        [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)].[ITEM #]  = [Supply Purchases TABLE].[ITEM #]
    SET [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)].PQUANTITY = [MAIN (WAREHOUSE STOCK)].PQUANTITY + [Supply Purchases TABLE]![QTY ADDED];
```

But you should rethink you data structure, as usuallay you have only one table for transactions (IN/OUT) and compute the actual stock when needed. See [Ms Featured Access Templates Inventory](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/featured-access-templates-e14f25e4-78b6-41de-8278-1afcfc91a9cb?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) and [Allen Browne AppInventory](http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html) for some hints.

Comment: Tried this but for some reason PQuantity doubles up every time I enter a new record. Is there a string that resets the formula so it doesn't do this?